# Does Wordpress have a built in message function for presenting notifications to users?

Tags: notifications

Does Wordpress have something similar to Drupal's [drupal_set_message](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_set_message/7) function? I want to notify the user of something and was hoping there was a built in API call to do this.

Comment: Where do you want to notify the user? WordPress has nothing like this built-in, so you'll have to either find a plug-in or roll your own using something like [Toastr](https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr) (if you want pop-ups).

Comment: A client wants us to redirect to the homepage when a contributor submits a post for review instead of back to the edit post screen. I want to let the user know that their post has been submitted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an idea: use the [`save_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post) hook to set a session containing the message you want to show the user and then redirect to the home page. In the home page template, check for the presence of that session and show the message to the user.

Something like this:

functions.php:

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'wpse60249_save_post' );

function wpse60249_save_post( $post_id ) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION[ 'message' ] = __( 'Your text here...' );
}
```

index.php (or appropriate template):

```
if ( isset( $_SESSION[ 'message' ] ) :
    echo $_SESSION[ 'message' ];
    unset( $_SESSION[ 'message' ] );
endif;
```

---

**Edit 10/21/2012**

When I wrote this answer, I did not know that WordPress resets the `$_SESSION` variable but I learned that a couple of weeks ago while working on a project for a client. Thanks for the reminder about this question, @kaiser! Here is updated code using [transients](http://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API) instead:

`functions.php`:

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'wpse60249_save_post' );

function wpse60249_save_post( $post_id ) {
    session_start();
    set_transient( 'temporary_message', __( 'Your text here...' ), 60*60*12 );
}
```

`index.php` (or appropriate template):

```
if ( false !== ( $temp_message = get_transient( 'temporary_message' ) ) :
    echo $temp_message;
    delete_transient( 'temporary_message' );
endif;
```

Comment: That was what I was thinking...but WP doesn't support sessions so well :s I'll see what I can come up with. Thanks ;)

Comment: Check out [this article](http://devondev.com/2012/02/03/using-the-php-session-in-wordpress/).

Comment: `$_SESSION` doesn't work properly in WP. They get unset by core during start up/request start.

Comment: Are transients somehow tied to the particular user viewing the page like sessions? Wouldn't the edited code using transients show the message for all users.  Although with the delete the window of time is pretty short, it still seems possible for another user to get the message instead or also.

Comment: you are missing a braked in the else

Answer (score 2):

There's an update and an error message, that you can use on the `admin_notices` hook.

### Test Plugin

```
/* Plugin Name: Admin Notice w test message */
function wpse60244_custom_admin_notice()
{
    return print '<div id="message" class="updated fade"><p><strong>Hi!</strong> Look at me! In theory I should even fade out after a short time span!</p></div>';
}
add_action( 'admin_notices', 'wpse60244_custom_admin_notice' );
```

You can throw this in your plugins folder and give it a test.

### Sidenotes

You could - in theory also use the `admin_head` hook to trigger the adding of the action. If you only need it on specific admin UI screens/pages, then check for `global $taxnow, $pagenow;` or use the `admin_head-{$hook_suffix}` hook.

Comment: Thanks Kaiser; I had forgotten about that. I assumed he wanted the message to show on the front end, though. Btw: `return print`?! Hehe ;-)

Comment: @Joseph Little tired today. What about `return print`?

Comment: I guess that is valid - I thought that `print` didn't return anything but according to [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print.php), it *always* returns 1.